# Power Automate Browser extension Desktop VS Online

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I've made a desktop automation that opens Microsoft Edge and then fills in a form. Works fine when I start the automation form the desktop version. But when I start this automation from Power Automate (online) with a recurrence trigger it stops working after opening the browser. Looks like it loses the connection with the browser directly after starting Edge. The step 'Start browser' does not finish.

Hope someone can help, thanx in advance.

Edit: I found that it has something to do with the Edge extension. I could turn it on for the desktop version, but I can't find where I can turn it on for the 'online' version...

Comment: there is no explanation about what power automate tools you are using, what are the conditions whatsoever. Please provide info on those